# Ruby: Storing a Hash in a Hash with default value Hash, for non-existent key

Tags: ruby

Why does attempting to store nested values for `Hash.new({})` work the way it does? What's actually happening under the hood? What would its use-case be?

When creating a Hash that has a default value of {}

```
a = Hash.new({})
=> {}
a.default
=> {}
```

querying a non-existent key will return an empty hash as expected

```
a[:foo]
=> {}
```

however when attempting to assign a value to a key that does not yet exist

```
a[:foo][:bar] = 'baz'
=> "baz"
```

the hash still appears to be empty

```
a
=> {}
```

however fetching the parent key will return the nested hash.

```
a[:foo]
=> {:bar=>"baz"}
```

Even more confusingly, this new hash has now become the parent hash's default value

```
a.default
=> {:bar=>"baz"}
```

such that querying a non-existent key will return that value

```
a[:biz]
=> {:bar=>"baz"}
```

This can be solved by doing

```
a[:foo] = {} unless a.key? :foo
a[:foo][:bar] = 'baz'
a
=> {:foo=>{:bar=>"baz"}}
```

Other similar questions also suggest `a = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }` which works for storing new keys, but also creates empty hashes for fetch operations e.g.

```
a[:baz] == 2
a
=> {:baz=>{}}
```

Is there some way, other than writing a method, to get the hash to create nested hashes if necessary when storing values, but not when fetching values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that in Ruby<sup>1</sup> you're storing a default *object reference*, not a default that's *cloned*. Even though it isn't your intent, you're asking for the default for any missing key to be the *same object*. For simple values like `Hash.new(0)` the default isn't altered when a new value is assigned, it's *replaced*, but with a nested hash you're explicitly altering the value.

What you want is this expressed more minimally as:

```rb
a = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { } }
```

If you're ever confused by why things end up blending like this, check with `object_id` which tells you the "identity" of a given object.

Consider:

```rb
a = Hash.new({ })
a[0].object_id == a[1].object_id
# => true

b = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { } }
b[0].object_id == b[1].object_id
# => false
```

Where here you can see each "slot" is independent.

One downside to these auto-instantiating models is, as you point out, it will create entries you may not necessarily want. To avoid that you'll need to tread more carefully, as in:

```
if a.key?(:baz) && a[:baz] == 2
  # ...
end
```

--

<sup>1</sup> JavaScript, Python and others also exhibit this behaviour, at least for non-primitive types.

Comment: Readers: it's also helpful to closely examine the docs for [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), [Hash#default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-default), [Hash#default_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) and, tangentially related, [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch). Note `h.default` merely returns a value; it does not alter the hash.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create empty hashes for fetch operations, you can use #freeze to protect the default value from accidental modification.

```rb
a = Hash.new({}.freeze)
a[:foo]  #=> {}
a #=> {} still empty, no :foo key created
a[:foo][:bar] = 'baz' #FrozenError because you're trying to modify the default value
a[:foo] = a[:foo].merge(:bar => 'baz')
a #=> {:foo=>{:bar=>"baz"}}
```